# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop' when running music bot discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to code a simple music bot with discord.py following a tutorial. However when I use '<play' it shows me this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'. Please help, thank you.

```
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
      
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
```

Comment: Hey vivienne, welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you be able to [edit] your question to trim the code down to a [mcve]? This would help others with the same issue better identify if they are facing the same problem as you. In my opinion, only the `play` command is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.voice_client` can be None if the bot is not connected to any voice channel. In that case, you can't use `stop()`. You can prevent this by implementing a check.

```py
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        # bot is not connected to a voice channel
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    else:
        # bot is already connected to a voice channel
```

I would also implement a statement to check to see if the user is connected to any voice channel.

```py
if ctx.author.voice is None:
    await ctx.send("You are not connected to any voice channel!")
else:
    # user is connected to a voice channel
```